# Adding items dynamically in nativescript-pager screws up view order

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I am using pagination inside my pager but this seems to bug out the whole pager.
I made a test using some simple data.
Expected behaviour would be to start counting from 1 to 7 and then restart counting from 1 to 7.
Like this: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4,5,6,7

But what actually happens is the following: 1,2,3,4,5,6,6,7,1,2,4,5,6,1,5,5,4

**Inside Template**

```
        <Pager height="100%" width="100%" @selectedIndexChange="onPagerChangedPage($event)" @loaded="onPagerLoaded($event)" for="item in profiles">
            <v-template>
              <StackLayout height="100%" width="100%" class="profile-wrapper">
                <Label :text="item.first_name"/>
              </StackLayout>
            </v-template>
          </Pager>
```

**Data**

```
  data() {
    return {
          profiles: new ObservableArray( [ { first_name: "1.hello"},{ first_name: "2.brah"}, {first_name: "3.krakaka"},{first_name: "4.Blalala"},{first_name: "5.Shatash"},{first_name: "6.Dreaum"},{first_name: "7.Breauhjm"} ]),
      }
  }
```

**Methods**

```
    onPagerChangedPage(event) {
      let profileCount = event + 1;
      if (this.profiles.length === profileCount) {
        this.getProfiles();
      }
    },
    getProfiles() {
      let newProfiles = [{first_name: "1.hello"},{first_name: "2.brah"}, {first_name: "3.krakaka"},{first_name: "4.Blalala"},{first_name: "5.Shatash"},{first_name: "6.Dreaum"},{first_name: "7.Breauhjm"}];
      newProfiles.forEach(profile => {
        this.profiles.push(profile);
      });
    },
```

**EDIT: tried some new methods**

```
    onLoadMoreItems(event) {
      let profileCount = this.profiles.length + 1;
      this.profiles.push({first_name: profileCount + ": random"});
    },
    onPagerChangedPage(event) {
      console.log("Current page name:" + this.profiles.getItem(event).first_name);
      let profileCount = event + 1;
      console.log(profileCount + "|" + this.profiles.length);
    },
```

[image: Pager does not seem to correctly fill in the new pages]

Answer (score 0):

That can be fixed by using an ObservableArray it is handled better internally since it emits data change events, if you are wondering it has about the same amount of  methods as a regular array .... `import {ObservableArray} from 'tns-core-modules/data/observable-array'`

Comment: First off thanks for answering on my question. I tried using a ObservableArray but I still get the same sequence of numbers. Do you have any other ideas how to fix this issue?

Comment: Which version are you using also there is a similar example to this in the repo

Comment: Could you link me to the demo? I just browsed through the demos but I can't seem to find a demo where he is also removing/adding items dynamically.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/triniwiz/nativescript-pager/blob/master/demo/app/main-page.ts#L15)  the we bind to `loadMoreItems` event

Comment: I still can't seem to get it work. When I log a item inside the array via selectedIndex I get the correct name but the pager does not contain that item. IE: "console.log("Current page name:" + this.profiles.getItem(event).first_name);" Correct but page shows wrong first_name.

Comment: I editted my question with some new information maybe you can check it out?

Comment: Which version of the plugin is this ?

Comment: The plugin version I am using is: 11.0.10

Comment: @Mennolp did you ever figure this one out?